# Unzip Running on Linux using -d and overwrite together

Tags: php, linux, directory, unzip

i am trying to use unzip in order to pull files , extract them on a local server and upload to S3.

my sctipt get stuck due to overwrite flag :

```
eplace /home/folder1/tmp/creative_tmp/5a558e1d4337410887ffde9c8aeff90b_Burger_250x350.jpg? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

i run the following command at the server :

```
unzip -d /home/folder1/tmp/creative_tmp/large_image_file.zip
```

now i need to add -o to the unzip command like so :

```
unzip -o /path/to/archive.zip
```

But i also need to run the -d option for unzipping the Zip file at the right location.

i tried some combinations and i didn't get it to work. i will appreciate your help with this . Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
unzip -o -d /path/to/folder /path/to/archive.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
unzip -o /path/of/zipfile.zip -d /path/to/unzip/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).